# How to insert and update checkbox value correctly into database?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, checkbox

I'm working on a JSP application and I have a form which has a checkbox, what I try to do is to insert and update into my DB "0 or 1" depending if it's checked or unchecked. What my code does already is to insert "1" always insert "1" instead of "0" if it's unchecked and when I try to update my DB, example from "1" to "0" or form "0" to "1", It does not do the work, my checkbox does not toggle. Please help me!

I already have my method to insert and update and it works, because I can insert or update the additional fields of the form.

JSP code:

```
<tr>
<td>Principal:</td>
<td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" id="a_principal" name="a_principal" value="<%=directorio!=null?(directorio.isPrincipal()!=false?directorio.isPrincipal(): ""):""%>" />
<%=directorio.isPrincipal()%>
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(function (){  
    if($('#a_principal').val()== "true"){           
         $("input:checkbox").prop('checked',true);        
    }else{
        $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);        
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If i was you I would to try to display something inside your if/else statement and see which of them is executing (that is if they are executing at all).

Also you can try to change you if statement to

```
    if($('#a_principal').val() === true) { ...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@paulinajr I hope your script updates only state of check-box not the value. Instead what you can do is debug your servlet/java code by IDE like eclipse. If i am right you will receive the status of check-box in your servlet code like **on**. You can check it like

```
if (request.your_getterProperty().equalsIgnoreCase("on")
    && !request.your_getterProperty().isEmpty()) {
// Do the stuff
}
```

Let me know if this helps..